# expressStaticGzip does not compress files

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, gzip, brotli

I would like to compress js and css files. I am using the [expressStaticGzip][1] module.

As you might have figured out, the response is not being compressed (at all). Neither Brotli nor Gzip is being used.

The (relevant) code in my app.js looks like this

```
const expressStaticGzip = require('express-static-gzip'); //compression

//-- compression --//
app.use('/public', expressStaticGzip(path.join(__dirname, 'static', 'public'), {
    enableBrotli: true, // Enable Brotli compression
    orderPreference: ['br', 'gz'], // Prefer Brotli over gzip
}));

app.use(express.static('static'));
```

My folder structure looks like this:

```
static
--public
----css
----js
app.js
```

As far as I understand, any request made to `public` should compress the files into `br` or `gzip`, whichever the client supports.

If we look at the `devTools`, `network` tab this is shown:

```
GET 
    https://localhost/public/css/main/main.min.css

Response Headers:
Accept-Ranges
    bytes
Cache-Control
    public, max-age=0
Connection
    keep-alive
Content-Length
    14333
Content-Type
    text/css; charset=UTF-8
Date
    Fri, 08 Sep 2023 13:48:30 GMT
ETag
    W/"37fd-18a657d2170"
Keep-Alive
    timeout=5
Last-Modified
    Tue, 05 Sep 2023 13:16:54 GMT
X-Powered-By
    Express

Request Headers:
Accept
    text/css,*/*;q=0.1
Accept-Encoding
    gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language
    en-GB,en;q=0.5
Cache-Control
    no-cache
Connection
    keep-alive
DNT
    1
Host
    localhost
Pragma
    no-cache
Referer
    https://localhost/refering/page
Sec-Fetch-Dest
    style
Sec-Fetch-Mode
    no-cors
Sec-Fetch-Site
    same-origin
User-Agent
    Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/117.0
```

GET https://localhost/**public**/css/main/main.min.css

the GET contains public, so it should be compressed.

Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate, br

gzip and br are accepted as encoding.

So I am wondering why doesn't this work. Any help, tips or questions for clarification are welcome.

Thank you.

**Edit**

Since I couldn't get it to work, I'm now using `compression`. Works out of the box.

```
const compression = require('compression') //compression

app.use(compression());
```

I would still like to serve Brotli if possible, so I will leave the question open for now, if someone can point me in the right direction.
[1]: https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-static-gzip